# How to access cordova features in swift?

Tags: swift, shell, cordova, terminal

I am trying to create a cordova project manager just form myself in xcode 7 using swift. I created a cocoa class for my Cordova functions, but I am stuck at even creating the cordova project. The class looks like this:

```
class Cordova: NSObject {

    let path:String = ""

    func create ( path:String ) -> Int32 {
        let task:NSTask = NSTask()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova" //????
        task.arguments = ["codova", "create", path]
        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
        return task.terminationStatus
    }
}
```

This fires from a UI event (a button click obviously). The problem is, that I cannot access the cordova terminal features like this, and I don't know what the problem could be.

This code by the way works with for example mkdir, so the problem really is cordova inside the command line. I am getting this error:

```
Couldn't posix_spawn: error 13
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could use Cordova in a web view to access the desired functions and make a hybrid app.

Comment: Could you explain that a little more? @Phoen1xUK

Comment: I don't know fully how Cordova works, hence the comments rather than an answer. Check out [this Cordova documentation about iOS web views](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/ios/webview.html). It's written for obj-c, but I imagine the same principles apply.

Comment: @Phoen1xUK, that's not what he is asking, he really wants to execute node commands using swift

Comment: @Phoen1xUK what jcesarmobile sais is correct